# JOGL draw VBO black screen

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I began to try to draw VBO using JOGL. Prior to that, I drew with the help of glBegin and glEnd, and everything worked. And then I see only a black screen. What could be the problem? I read somewhere that using VBO for drawing requires shaders. Is it so?
Code:

```
public class Main implements GLEventListener {

       public static DisplayMode dm, dm_old;
       private GLU glu = new GLU();
       private float xrot,yrot,zrot;
       private int texture;
       Texture t;
       @Override
       public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
          final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
          gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
          gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The View
          gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, -5.0f);

          gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

          final float[] coordData = {
                  0, 0, //
                  1, 0, //
                  0, 1, //
          };
          final float[] vertices = {
                  -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
                  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
                  -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
          };
          // Setup the vertices into the buffer
          FloatBuffer verts = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(vertices.length);
          verts.put(vertices).position(0);

          // Setup the texture coordinates
          FloatBuffer coords = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(coordData.length);
          coords.put(coordData).position(0);

          gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, verts);
          gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, coords);
          gl.glDrawArrays(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

          //change the speeds here
          xrot += 5f;
       }

       @Override
       public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
          final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
          gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH);
          gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
          gl.glClearDepth(1.0f);
          gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
          gl.glDepthFunc(GL2.GL_LEQUAL);
          gl.glHint(GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST);

          gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
          try {
             File im = new File("/home/congard/pic/t.jpeg");
             t = TextureIO.newTexture(im, true);
             texture= t.getTextureObject(gl);

          }catch(IOException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }

       @Override
       public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
            // some code
       }
}
```

Comment: There are other mistakes in your source code. At first, you shouldn't call "new GLU()" directly, rather call GLU.createGLU(GL) in your method implementing GLEventListener.init(). I don't advise you to mix the low level texture API calls with the high level ones, either use the Texture object everywhere or use its identifier with glBindTexture(), ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't enable the client-side capabilities for vertex and texture coordinates. See [Client-Side Vertex Arrays](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Client-Side_Vertex_Arrays)
 and [`glEnableClientState`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml).

Add the following to your code:

```
gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, verts);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, coords);
```